# MKMapView : setRegion doesn't work !

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, mkmapview, region

Aaaarg... ok, let's calm myself.

Did someone have any problem with setting the region of a MKMapView ?
It never worked with me.

This code :

```
-(void)setUserCenteredSpan:(MKCoordinateSpan)span{ // for this example, span = {0.5, 0.5}
    // Current region (just initialised)
NSLog(@"%f, %f - %f, %f",   self.region.center.latitude,
                            self.region.center.longitude, 
                            self.region.span.latitudeDelta, 
                            self.region.span.longitudeDelta);
    // New Region
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMake([[[self userLocation] location] coordinate],
                                                   span);
NSLog(@"%f, %f - %f, %f",   region.center.latitude,
                            region.center.longitude, 
                            region.span.latitudeDelta, 
                            region.span.longitudeDelta);
    // Region saved in MKMapView
[self setRegion:region animated:NO];
NSLog(@"%f, %f - %f, %f",   self.region.center.latitude,
                            self.region.center.longitude, 
                            self.region.span.latitudeDelta, 
                            self.region.span.longitudeDelta);
}
```

Returns that log :

```
30.145127, -40.078125 - 0.000000, 0.000000
0.000000, 0.000000 - 0.500000, 0.500000
0.000000, 0.000000 - 0.000000, 0.000000
```

Do you know why ??!

Thanks a lot, you can save me from killing myself X(

Mart

EDIT : Of course, I am on the device, connected to internet.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't understand exactly the previous logs, but I know where was my error.

The instancied MKMapView was not initialised with a frame, but with an autoresizingMask set to > 0.

When the setRegion method was called, my view was not framed yet. I think the region values are calculated according to the view frame, so these values couldn't be found.

Just set the frame before doing a setRegion, and it would display normally.

Bye !

Comment: Indeed. I was setting the region of a mapView in the controller's `viewDidLoad`, but alas the frame size was (0,0). Setting the region has no effect until the view's frame is established (apparently). The frame should be set by the time `viewDidAppear` is invoked.

Comment: thank you for this, you just saved another night of hair pulling.  Interestingly, I was following a Ray Wenderlich tutorial which said that viewWillAppear will work, but did not for me.  Not sure why, but viewDidAppear did the trick!

Comment: That is beautiful! +1

Answer (score 1):

Your first log uses `self.region.center.latitude`, but I don't see that anywhere in your call to `MKCoordinateRegionMake`.  The log is telling you that whatever you are using to make the region to set, has a lat/long of 0/0...

Comment: [[[self userLocation] location] coordinate] should return the lat/long of the user position.
MKCoordinateRegionMake's first arg should set the lat/long of the user position, be it remains 0/0...

Answer (score 1):

Setting the AutoResizing Mask helped me.

```
[_mapView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
```