# Open MKMapView to the users current location without starting at US zoom level

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview

I am using the MKMap view, but when the map first loads it show the entire United States. Then it zooms to my current location.

Is there a way to make the map load to a specific zoom level?

I start the CLLocationManager and implemented the following method.

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
```

I also use `setRegion` but no matter what I do the map always starts at US level then zooms to the region I set with `setRegion`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that `setRegion` doesn't work.

I found this post: [MKMapView : setRegion doesn't work !](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426557/mkmapview-setregion-doesnt-work)

It seems to be a similar problem. If you are setting the MKMapView's region early, in `viewDidLoad`?, it's possible that the MapView hasn't acquired it's final frame yet. Try moving your `setRegion` to `viewDidAppear` and see if it makes a difference.

Cheers!